# minimalist serial port addon to a basic 8052

Tags: microcontroller, serial, uart, rs232, 8051

Currently I have two microcontrollers connected to each other so that I have two serial ports. One to the PC and one to a wireless radio module.

Now I'm considering replacing one microcontroller with a hardware UART so that I can exchange parallel data to the PC. I'm avoiding parallel port because fewer PC's come with parallel ports.

I have a few questions:

Can I achieve 56kbps if I place this UART in synchronous mode?

Can I send a byte of data to the uart by applying data to the P1 line and pulsing WR low when a signal on the UART is in a ready state?

Can I receive a byte in a similar way (where I pulse RD low instead and receive contents on P1)?

Will I always need to receive and process data within a certain time limit especially if the PC decides to ignore any flow control in use by the UART?

[image: circuit]

Comment: what is `P1 line`? ..... have you referred to the hardware UART datasheet for the answers?

Comment: Why the 8052? Is this a school assignment?

Comment: It is what I have and for its price point, its much cheaper plus I even can program it easier than other chips.